# Accessing array position returns undefined in JavaScript using Azure platform

Tags: javascript, arrays, azure, serverside-javascript

I have the following JavaScript object:

```
var payload = {
    "data": {
        "title": item.title,
        "time": item.time,
        "location": item.location,
        "latitude": item.latitude,
        "longitude": item.longitude,
        "invites": item.invites,
        "encodedImage": item.encondedImage        
    }
};
```

`item.invites` is a big string separated by commas. I use a function to split the string into an array based on the commas:

```
var userIdArray = splitArray(item.invites);
userIdArray.pop(); //last element is empty

//further down...
function splitArray(str) {
    var array = new Array(); //explicitly declared out of despair
    array = str.split(",");    
    return array;
}
```

and then I iterate it like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < userIdArray.length; i++) {
     request.execute({
         success: function() {
            console.log("User: " + userIdArray[i]); //prints undefined...
```

But even though `console.log(userIdArray);` prints the array normally, I get undefined if the array is only 1 in length, but if it's 2 it prints the *2nd* element... Why is this happening?

Comment: The reason for this is that the function is called later and `i` by that time is equal to `userIdArray.length` (end of loop with subsequent `i++`) which of course is not a valid index of the array.

Comment: Well it only iterates once if the array is 1 position long.
i will only be 0 since i < userIdArray.length won't let it equal 1 right?

Comment: Still the same: when the loop iterates once, `i` in the end will be `1` whereas the maximum index will be `0`. `i++` is the final statement that gets executed at the end of the `for` loop.

Comment: So it should be i < userIdArray.length - 1 ? Or protect with an if statement?
I feel like JS arrays are much like C arrays but I always seem to screw up when I miss with them... Pardon my noobness

Comment: No, that won’t help you at all… I’m actually not exactly sure how to do it either…

Comment: Maybe a separate function call for when the length is just 1?... even thought I rather have an elegant solution for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Azure, but going by the general pattern of the code, it  seems that `success` is a function which will execute in the future and is not tied to the loop scope: therefore it will see a bad counter variable `[i]` value when the handler executes.

(Also, it may not pose a problem, but a counter variable declared and initialized in the loop header is a code smell, and possibly problematic.)

Without looking at the complete code, I can't tell if [i] is a global or local to a wrapping function, but I think it is global since you didn't get a ReferenceError.

The loop executes without waiting for all the future success calls (which are are async-stacked and not synchronous with the loop body), and so the last  `[i++]` is evaluated at array.length, which will always be undefined since we're indexing past the array.

request.execute is synchronous and will be dispatched as expected from within the loop body, but the success handler is surely not.

As for the expressing the intention correctly in code, I think that an IIFE might fix this: (I have zero idea what request.execute does and if calling execute on the same object time and again is ok, hence I say it *might*):

```
for (var i = 0; i < userIdArray.length; i++) {
     request.execute({
        success: (function (counter) {
            return function () {
                console.log("User: " + userIdArray[counter]);
            }
        }(i))
    });
 }
```

*I'm throwing a reasonable guess here. That aside, I think the code needs significant re-thinking and refactoring. Callbacks in loops usually indicate a major logical flaw.*

Comment: This did the trick! I guess I'm not used to async programming yet. The loop has since been moved to inside execute, I didn't realise how bad that was at first glance. Thanks for the great tips, and kudos on your code-sense, you got it right. Also welcome to stackoverflow!